# box-shadow при использовании box-shadow появляются полупрозрачные линии, как избавится?

Tags: html, css, scss

Пытаюсь сделать треугольник с закругленными углами. Посмотрел урок в ютубе, пробую и не получается.

Вот макет треугольника:
https://wampi.ru/image/R0QHj7V (размеры треугольника 10x11)

То что у меня получилось:
https://wampi.ru/image/R0QLefH

Проблемы:

1. Не знаю как сделать углы более острыми
2. Как убрать линии у box-shadow и как они вообще образовались

```css
.play_circle {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%; 
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.play_area {
    font-size: 65.5%;
}

.play_triangle,
.play_triangle::after,
.play_triangle::before {
    width: .2em;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: #5E81FF;
    border-radius: 10em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .2em #5E81FF;
}

.play_triangle {
    position: relative;
    left: -.2em;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

.play_triangle::after,
.play_triangle::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: .2em;
}

.play_triangle::before {
    top: -.3em;
    left: .4em;
    height: 1.1em;
    transform: rotate(-62.964deg);
}

.play_triangle::after {
    top: .2em;
    left: .4em;
    height: 1.1em;
    transform: rotate(62.964deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="play_circle">
                <div class="play_area">
                    <div class="play_triangle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ```svg icon```?

Comment: Да можно скачать svg, но я решил поизврощаться и сделать с помощью такой фигнулины